# Updated spfx yeoman generator now I get a bunch of errors

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, pnp-js

So I ran
npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest -g

Now I have a bunch of errors in my WebPart.ts files

spfxContext is highlighted and the error is ...

(property) ILibraryConfiguration.spfxContext?: ISPFXContext
Used to supply the current context from an SPFx webpart to the library

Type 'WebPartContext' is not assignable to type 'ISPFXContext'.ts(2322)

protected onInit(): Promise {

```
sp.setup({

spfxContext: this.context

});

return super.onInit();
```

}

thanks
P

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using **pnpjs** library (the line that gives the error is the initialization of the pnpjs library), try updating the pnpjs library to the latest version. Please note that pnpjs is a separate library (is not a part of the SPFx framework).

More info: https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/2329

Alternatively, just could simply cast the spfx context like this:

```
sp.setup({
  spfxContext: this.context as any
});
```